# Monitoring app launches on an iOS device

Tags: ios4, background, monitoring

While I'm no expert on iOS development, I have read through the API docs on Apple's developer site and I can't find anything on this. Before I presume that it's impossible let me ask here: Can I somehow monitor application launches on a standard iOS device? By "standard" I mean **not** jailbroken and using only public iOS v4 APIs. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You realize what you want is a potential security issue, right?

Comment: A privacy issue perhaps, though the user would have to install the app themselves. I promise to use my powers for good and not for evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no access to system-level stuff like that at all. The somewhat-small sandbox makes certain types of apps impossible, but does provide a lot of protection for the user.